# Free Cryptography libraries

Tags: c#, c++, python, cryptography

What are the most stable and useful Cryptography libraries, that they are:

- written with/for python, c++, c#, .net
- opensource, GNU, or other free license

Comment: See related questions for dupes including http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1343977/choosing-a-cryptography-library

Comment: You should also mention that the libraries must be downloadable from Iran, as many countries may block that (sorry, I don't know the details or where you might best download from, I'm just pointing out that you should edit the question to make this requirement explicit).

Comment: @Alex: As an example, which open source cryptography library can't be downloaded from Iran?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard Python library (implementing common ciphers like AES and RSA) is [PyCrypto](http://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/). It doesn't support things like [PKCS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PKCS) yet, however. There is a partial Python wrapper for the Crypto++ library given by [PyCryptopp](http://allmydata.org/trac/pycryptopp), which you may find useful.

The OpenSSL library is also wrapped for Python by [PyOpenSSL](https://launchpad.net/pyopenssl). A Python implementation of SSH is [Paramiko](http://www.lag.net/paramiko/).

Comment: [PyCrypto](https://www.pycrypto.org/) is no longer supported. [PyCryptoDome](https://pypi.org/project/pycryptodome/) is a fork of the original library and is considered a suitable replacement.

Answer (score 2):

For C# and Java, there is [bouncycastle](http://www.bouncycastle.org). The granddaddy of crypto libraries is [openssl](http://www.openssl.org). For C++, another very mature library is [crypto++](http://www.cryptopp.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [KeyCzar](http://www.keyczar.org/)

> Some features of Keyczar include:
>
> - A simple API
> - Key rotation and versioning
> - Safe default algorithms, modes, and key lengths
> - Automated generation of initialization vectors and ciphertext signatures
> - Java, Python, and C++ implementations
> - International support in Java (Python coming soon)

Doesn't seem to have C# support though.

Comment: @matt b: it's blocked for my country:   You are accessing this page from a forbidden country. has a mirror?

Comment: that's blocked too:Your client does not have permission to get URL /p/keyczar/ from this server. try to access from Iran

Answer (score 0):

[NSS](http://www.mozilla.org/projects/security/pki/nss/) works with C++, and has bindings for Java and Python, although I'm not sure if it has .NET/Mono bindings yet.