# Python Boto S3Connection through proxy

Tags: python, proxy, amazon-s3, boto, password-encryption

I am building a web app that will automatically download some data from Amazon's S3 cloud, unzip and load the unzipped data into a PostGRE SQL database.

I have all the scripts developed and working. However, I'd like to create a front-end where a user would put their username and password for a proxy server. This is necessary as users are required to change those every month.

I'm using boto to connect to S3. Up until now, since I was executing the scripts myself from the command line, I was just typing in my password as it was. I'd like to change that and use jQuery to pass username and encrypted password to a Python script that will then do all the above mentioned actions. I'd like to avoid sending this through the list of parameters in web browser's address line.

I know how to do the hashing (I think). However, when I'm trying to pass hashed password to boto I get an error `407 (Proxy Authentication Required)`.

Does anyone know a workaround this? I'm happy to use a module other than Boto as long as I can pass encrypted password. Unless I can 'unhash' the password in the script and then pass it to Boto.S3Connection.

Here's the script that I'm using to connect to S3.

```
import boto 
import sys, os
from boto.s3.key import Key
import boto.s3.connection as s3
import argparse

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = 'YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY'

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Do something')
parser.add_argument('user', metavar='user', nargs='+', help='user login to access proxy')
parser.add_argument('passwd', metavar='passwd', nargs='+', help='user password')

args = parser.parse_args()
bucket_name = 'xxxx.xxx.xxx'

# connect to the bucket
conn = s3.S3Connection(AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, 
      proxy='999.999.99.99',
      proxy_port='8080', 
      proxy_user=args.user[0], 
      proxy_pass=args.passwd[0])

# do whatever is necessary below ...
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: By reading [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2760911/is-a-there-md5-decrypt-function-in-python) I now know that I cannot unhash once hashed password (one-way encoding). I can do the reversal with RSA encrypting and I think I'll go with that. Any other suggestions welcome.